# What's a good reference for creating and updating Performance Counters in unmanaged code?

Tags: c++, windows, unmanaged, performancecounter

I have several apps that need to create and write to Performance Counters. One of them is written in C++. Currently, upgrading that app to .NET is not an option. Where is a good resource for accessing Performance Counters using unmanaged code?

Thanks!

Comment: I feel for ya.  This is much harder than it needs to be or you would expect it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373209(v=VS.85).aspx

Note that how you publish the data depends on your OS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373165(v=VS.85).aspx